# Crash in release mode, not in debug mode

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a Windows console application in Visual Studio Express 2013. It compiles and runs fine in Debug mode, but the Release version crashes (*Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF*).
There are several similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to resolve my issue. They are typically related to **uninitialized variables**, **accessing elements beyond the bounds of an array**, **pointer arithmetic**, or **dynamically allocated memory**. I don't think any of these apply here, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

I've pared down the code considerably (the original was between 1000 and 2000 lines), each time removing code and checking that it still crashes. I can't seem to make it any smaller and still have the bug show up. With the code so simple now, I'm at a loss as to where the bug is. It's probably a standard C++ mistake (I'm pretty new to the language). I hate to ask such a generic question, but:

> Where is the bug in the following code?

Almost anything I take out now makes the bug disappear. It also disappears when I disable optimizations (or even when I optimize, but disable inlining).
My only suspicion is that it might be related to the vector of vectors (left_neighbors).

**Point.h**

```
#pragma once
class Point {
public:
    double x, y;
    Point(double xcoord, double ycoord);
};
```

**Point.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(double xcoord, double ycoord) {
    x = xcoord;
    y = ycoord;
}
```

**Diagram.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>

class Diagram
{
public:
    void check_for_crossing();
    std::vector<Point> vertices;
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> left_neighbors;
};
```

**Diagram.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Diagram.h"

double y_coordinate_of_segment_at(const Point start, const Point end, const double x) {
    return (start.y + (x - start.x) / (end.x - start.x) * (end.y - start.y));
}

void Diagram::check_for_crossing() {
    Point end1 = Point(1.5, 0.2);
    Point end2 = Point(2.8, 3.4);

    double y1_at_min = y_coordinate_of_segment_at(Point(0.5, 0.5), end1, 0.5);
    double y2_at_min = y_coordinate_of_segment_at(Point(1.5, 0.2), end2, 0.5);

    Point intersection(0.0, 0.0);
    intersection.x = (y2_at_min - y1_at_min) / (y2_at_min); // y2_at_min is not 0
    intersection.y = y_coordinate_of_segment_at(Point(0.5, 0.5), end1, intersection.x);
    vertices.push_back(intersection);

    left_neighbors.push_back({ 0, 1 });
}
```

**Berlin.cpp** (this is where the main function resides)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Diagram.h"

Diagram create_diagram() {
    Diagram diagram;
    diagram.vertices.push_back(Point(2.8, 3.4));
    return diagram;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Diagram diag = create_diagram();
    diag.check_for_crossing();

    return 0;
}
```

The only other files in the project are **stdafx.h** and **stdafx.cpp**, which are for precompiled headers. The contents of **stdafx.cpp** are only *#include "stdafx.h"*, and **stdafx.h** is empty.

Comment: You can still debug release mode, just make sure it's producing a *.pdb file.

Comment: I can't find anything. Try downloading Visual Studio 2015 Community and see if it still crashes there.

Comment: You use size_t for neighbours which is unsigned. Could it be that you somewhere assign -1 as neighbour count and implicitly assume it is an int? That can give funny errors.

Comment: Select `RelWithDebInfo` and hit `F5`

Comment: Good job on the repro code.  AVEs with an address of 0xfffffffff are usually alignment problems.  It is here, VS2013 is not squeaky clean there and updating to VS2015 would be wise.  The simplest workaround is Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable enhanced instruction set = /arch:SSE

Comment: @RichardCritten - Hm, thanks, I wasn't really aware of this.

Comment: @AloisKraus - I don't think that's it, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @HansPassant - The workaround seems to work! Great!

Comment: If it is a defect in VS2013, is there a place where it is documented? It would make for a good answer to the question.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? I'm new to this stackexchange, so please tell me if I didn't follow the etiquette.

Comment: @mainactual - I don't have a configuration called `RelWithDebInfo`, but I found how to do this in another stackoverflow question. In any case, I'm going to try VS2015 now and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - Thanks! No crash in VS2015.